# Windows 10/11 HTTP Setup Trace Task wrong url added by netsh http add urlacl

Tags: windows, http, windows-10

I'm trying to understand why the 8888 port goeas from open to close by itself....

I suppose to open the port with this commmand run as administrator:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://127.0.0.1:8888/ user="outputof:whoami"
```

But in **Event log > Windows registers > System** I found these row:

```
The reservation for the namespace identified by the URL prefix http://127.0.0.1:8888:127.0.0.1/? been added.

Attempt to reserve the URL http://127.0.0.1:8888:127.0.0.1/. Status 0x0. Process ID 0x1A4C executable path \ Device \ HarddiskVolume3 \ Windows \ System32 \ netsh.exe, DESKTOP-LNE0MHB \ User DEMO
```

I've checked from admin command prompt :

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

It seems the port should be open:

```
Reserved URL            : http://192.168.1.155:8888/
    User: DESKTOP-LNE0MHB\DEMO
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1336458954-2914664476-3191138624-1001)

Reserved URL            : http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    User: DESKTOP-LNE0MHB\DEMO
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-1336458954-2914664476-3191138624-1001)
```

Can anyone please explain me why there are two occurrences of 127.0.0.1 and the connection is still refused on that port?

Comment: For the one that send me a -1, I'll would be gratefull to you if you could add an explanation.